# fabric-ca-client command line option for Subject Alternative Name

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Using fabric-ca-client to generate a CSR, how do I declare a Subject Alternative Name with the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--csr.hosts` flag when calling the `enroll` command.  It takes a comma-separated list of strings.